# What are the concerns of using Crate.io as a primary datastore?

Tags: crate

If I am correct, crate (crate.io) is backed by Elasticsearch (Lucene). Weren't there a few articles a month ago that said that ES lost some writes under heavy load? Are there any other concerns?

Answer (score 1):

You are right, Crate is backed by Elasticsearch. We think that the guys at elasticsearch are doing a great job on improving data consistency. A good read is http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/resiliency-elasticsearch/ which gives a pretty good overview about efforts towards reliability. We at Crate are confident that this storage engine is safe to use as primary store. We also see, that issues regarding this area are getting actively worked on by the Lucene and Elasticsearch Community.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently evaluating Crate.io as a primary datastore for work. As the above answer is vague and unspecific, maybe it's time for an update on this question here. There is a Dec.2016 keynote presentation out there from the Jepsen author Kyle Kingsbury on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eSaFVX4izsQ) who investigated Crate.io for some problems with the resiliency in Elasticsearch. The first 8 minutes are introduction, the Crate.io part is from 23:50 till 31:10.

For those of you who don't want to watch the full video, here is a short summary.
First, the test setup. They set up databases and a random pattern of clients with random queries. Also, they voluntarily introduced problems for the databases, like network partitioning. Secondly, the results. According to Kingsbury, there are two issues with ES resiliency. Both of them carry on to Crate.io. Let's get to the details...

## Dirty reads

The first one -  [ES #20031](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/20031) - is that ES may cause dirty reads, divergence and lost updates if network partitions occur. As of now - December 2017 - this issue is still open. In my opinion, it is possible for the same problems to occur if a node is unresponsive for extremely heavy duty, like during extensive querying, reindexing or garbage collection.

## Lost updates

According to Kingsbury, there is another problem ("Can promote stale binaries") with ES that cause updates to get completely lost when network partitioning occurs. It has been tagged as #20384 and there is [kind of a fix](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/20384) which Kingsbury summarizes as "partial". So, ES may still cause lost data upon writing.

## What does ES say?

On [the official site of ES about resiliency](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/resiliency/current/index.html), only one of the two problems - #20384 - is mentioned. It has been marked as solved in the version [5.0 release notes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/release-notes-5.0.0.html), although the official site says that there is only a partial fix.

## What does Crate.io say?

On the [Crate.io documentation on resiliency](https://crate.io/docs/crate/guide/en/latest/best_practices/resilience.html), there is a list of known problems with Crate.io resiliency. The ES bug #20384 is commented as partially fixed and still causing an open problem. The ES bug #20031 is not mentioned. However, there is a paragraph about an issue with networking partition which Crate.io marked as fixed - so the official page is kind of inconclusive here.

## Conclusion

Kingsbury concluded in December 2016 that Crate.io should not be used as the primary data store. It could be used of course as a replication of your primary data to benefit from the time series database features that Crate.io offers. He also suggests that for machine data where 5% data loss is not a severe problem, Crate.io is a viable option as primary store.
It is my impression that some bugs Kingsbury reported may have been fixed but not all.